# MySQL Query multiple joins

Tags: mysql, left-join, max

I have the below query and it gives me the correct results for the most part.  The only thing is that there can be multiple photo with the same userid and I want it to pull the most recently uploaded photo.  Currently constituted it gives me a random photo.  I have a timestamp field in `tblimage`, but I don't know how to incorporate it into this query to pull the last photo uploaded.

```sql
SELECT tblimage.*, events.* 
  FROM (events LEFT JOIN tblfollowers
 ON events.id_user = tblfollowers.username) 
     LEFT JOIN tblimage ON events.id_user = tblimage.userid
     WHERE (((tblfollowers.follower_id)='$test') 
     AND (DATE_FORMAT(events.start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')='$today')) 
     OR (((tblfollowers.follower_id)='$test') 
     AND (DATE_FORMAT(events.end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')='$today')) 
     OR (((events.id_user) ='$test') 
     AND (DATE_FORMAT(events.start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')='$today')) 
     OR (((events.id_user) ='$test') 
     AND (DATE_FORMAT(events.end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')='$today')) 
GROUP BY  events.event_id
```

A few more details I thought I could share.  `tblimage` has the following records for example:

```
userid=25 photo = 1.png timestamp = 12:00 jan 19
userid=25 photo = 2.png timestamp = 1:00 jan 18
```

I want it to give me just the photo on jan 19.

Comment: If you are using MYSQL you might want to switch to MYSQLi or some thing else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end include

GROUP BY tblimage.userid Order By tblimage.userid DESC

and you have already included the Goup by so you will get the latest picture of the user.

Comment: Wasn't intended to be order by tblimage.timestamp?

Comment: @tariq it works like the way Ricardo said to do it.  Group BY events.id_user ORDER BY tblimage.timestamp DESC

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is pretty convoluted.

What you need is to put the following in the where clause:

```
events.start_date=MAX(events.start_date) OR events.end_date=MAX(events.end_date)
```

If there were multiple records for that date, it would return > 1, unless that date is a timestamp, then it would not.